# How does King of Dragon Pass for Windows handle saved games? How can I move them between PC's?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

I'm a big fan of King of Dragon Pass, but I've pretty much only played the iOS version. Now that the game is on [GOG](http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/king_of_dragon_pass), the itch has come upon me to rope a few friends into a good old fashioned [Succession Game](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuccessionGame).

However, before I drop the 30 bones on 5 copies of the game for me and said friends, I'd like to know just how easy or difficult it is to move save files around, since this varies wildly from game to game. Is it as simple as just attaching a small file to an email, and then dropping it in an appropriate directory? Or is it a complicated mess?

<sub>Given KODP's history of distribution on the PC, I find myself worrying it might be the latter.</sub>

Comment: It’s almost certainly the same two files on Steam (though they would not be compatible with other versions), but I have no Windows machine to check this on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save files are pretty visible, we wanted people to be able to mail the saga file.